# Basic routine of NotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So lets say I have class:

SurfaceLoad.cs

```
public class SurfaceLoad : Load
{
    private double force;
    public double Force{ get => force; set{force = value;}}

    public SurfaceLoad(double f){
        Force = f;
    }
    public SurfaceLoad(){
        Force = 0.0;
    }
}
```

And I have my ViewModel:

SurfaceLoadViewModel.cs

```
public class SurfaceLoadViewModel{

   private SurfaceLoad surfaceLoad = new SurfaceLoad();

   public double Force{
        get => surfaceLoad.Force;
        set{
            surfaceLoad.Force = value;
            NotifyPropertChanged("Force");
        } 
   } 

   public SurfaceLoadViewModel(){
   }
}
```

As I already found out, in a good MVVM-manner I have to put all the accessors for my SurfaceLoad-members into the ViewModel, as the Model itself should not contain any interaction-logic.

Question:

Now I have multiple implementations of Load (SurfaceLoad, PointLoad, AreaLoad,...). All of those are a member of the class called LoadContainer, which is only used to manage a package of loads, which occur at the same time.

**How do I efficiently manage all those types in a ViewModel? Do I have to wrap a Property around each and every value?**

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly asking, but `SurfaceLoad` or `Load` could implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged` themselves, so you could just expose a property of that type in your view model. So you do not have to have virtual properties that “reach into” the property there.

Comment: Exactly. It is *not* against MVVM principles to have a model that notifies about property changes. So just make Load implement INotifyPropertyChanged with a `NotifyPropertChanged` method that is accessible by derived classes.

Comment: So, when I apply the NotifyPropertyChanged to the Model, I will have to call the `PropertyChanged()` on every Member? Or is it sufficient to create the property with `{ get; set; }` in order to make it bindable?

Comment: Ok I got it, without the `NotifyPropertyChanged` I won't be able to update other Bindings. Means that if I change a value, the textboxes wont update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface in SurfaceLoad class.

```
    public class SurfaceLoad : Load, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double force;
        public double Force
        {
            get { return force; }
            set
            {
                force = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Force");
            }
        }
        public SurfaceLoad(double f)
        {
            Force = f;
        }
        public SurfaceLoad()
        {
            Force = 0.0;
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertySelector)
        {
            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChanged != null)
            {
                string propertyName = GetPropertyName(propertySelector);
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two comments have already helped me a lot.
In addition, I did some research and came to the conclusion that it is much more efficient to write the "NotifyPropertyChanged" handlers into the models, since this procedure does not work against the mvvm-principles!